# timescaledb slow in select... order by desc

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have created a timescaledb table but I think there is something wrong. I filled the table with round about 18,7 Mil rows and it takes more than 30 min to get a result.
Here is how I have created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE historydata(
uniqueid bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
sensorid integer NOT NULL,
processor1 integer,
processor2 integer,
processor3 integer,
processor4 integer,
processor5 integer,
processor6 integer,
processor7 integer,
processor8 integer,
processor9 integer,
processor10 integer,
processor11 integer,
processor12 integer,
processor13 integer,
processor14 integer,
processor15 integer,
processor16 integer,
freespace integer,
freebytes integer,
pingminimun integer,
pingmaximum integer,
pingtime integer,
pingpacketloss integer,
operatingstate text,
percentavailablememory numeric,
availablememory numeric,
totalmemory numeric,
total integer,
coverage integer,
CONSTRAINT historykey PRIMARY KEY (uniqueid, datetime));

select create_hypertable('historydata','datetime','uniqueid');
```

When I do a select * from historydata order by datetime desc

it takes more than 30 min to get something

What do I wrong?

Comment: If you have too much data it will be trying to fetch all data with no pagination. Have you tried to limit your query?

If you also limit the query with a where clause filtering by the datetime column, it will probably give you much faster results.

Comment: 'ERROR:  invalid number of partitions for dimension "uniqueid"'